# how to integrate login with react-router-dom v6, without being in navBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm intern and learning to use ReactJS. I made my route through the navigation menu (TopNav), however I can't put my login screen in my web application.
could you help me please? Obrigada

````
const App = () => {
    return(
     
           <BrowserRouter>
            <TopNav />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/horahora" element={<HoraHora />}/>
                    <Route path="/fornecimento" element={<Fornecimento />}/>
                    <Route path="/performance" element={<Performance />}/>
                    <Route path="/porcentagemOEE" element={<PorcentagemOEE />}/>
                    <Route path="/perdasDia" element={<PerdasDia />}/>
                    <Route path="/paretoPerdas" element={<ParetoPerdas />}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App; ,
```
````

Comment: Can you please explain your question little bit more ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Desculpa! Eu estou criando um sistema, onde eu ja criei o Login. As paginas do sistema estão na rota do menu de navegação. E eu não consigo incluir o login na rota, sem invalidar a rota do menu de navegação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can conditional render  `<TopNav />` if logged in show nav else hide
`{login ? <TopNav /> : null}` assume login is your internal state